# Given I know an isometric diamond map coordinate, how do I figure out which tile was clicked?

Tags: math, drawing, tiles, isometric

My tile engine is coming along.  It can draw square, hexagonal and isometric staggered viewpoints.  Where I'm struggling is with the isometric rotated (or diamond) viewpoint.  Below is a picture of a 10x10 diamond map and the (simplified) code used to draw it.  The tiles are 128x64.

http://garrypettet.com/images/forum_images/5%20col%20x%205%20rows.png

```
for row = 0 to rowLimit

  for column = 0 to columnLimit

    x = column * (TileWidth/2) + (row * (TileWidth/2)) + Origin.X
    y = (column * (TileHeight/2)) - (row * (TileHeight/2)) + Origin.Y

    // Draw the tile's image
    buffer.Graphics.DrawPicture(Tiles(column, row).Image, x, y)

  next column

next row

// Draw the buffer to the canvas
g.DrawPicture(buffer, 0, 0)
```

I know that this will draw the contents of the whole of Tiles() and not just those visible on screen but I'm trying to get the basics first.

What I can't figure out is an easy way to convert x,y coordinates on the map to tile column,row coordinates. I tried to reverse:

```
x = column * (TileWidth/2) + (row * (TileWidth/2)) + Origin.X
y = (column * (TileHeight/2)) - (row * (TileHeight/2)) + Origin.Y
```

To work out column and row given x and y and came up with this:

```
column = ((x/2) - (Origin.X/2) + y + Origin.Y) / TileHeight
row = ((x/2) - (Origin.X/2) - y - Origin.Y) / TileHeight
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Can anyone think of a better way to do this?  Is there a  better way to transform a grid of rectangles into a diamond and back again (given that I know very little about matrices....).

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I can follow the details of your problem, but if you are just looking to solve your formulas for `x` and `y` in terms of `column` and `row`, then

```
column=(x + y - (Origin.X + Origin.Y))/TileWidth
row = (x - y - (Origin.X - Origin.Y))/TileHeight
```

The easiest way to get these expression is to first add the expressions for `x` and `y` and solve for `column`, then subtract them and solve for `row`.